# Fitting linear function at leaves of a CatBoost model

Tags: python, lightgbm, catboost, catboostregressor

Is there an equivalent to the `linear_tree` [function](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#linear_tree) in LightGBM in the CatBoost library? I would like to use a linear function at the leaves instead of a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it appears the answer is no. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1340) for this feature request in CatBoost. In Nov 2020 it was added to the development plan, but the devs in charge saw quality improvements only on synthetic datasets, so they removed it from the plan for the time being (as of Jan 2022).